# Better way to use data set in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

We have created a custom dataset and populating it with some data.

Before adding data, we are adding columns in the data set as follows

```
DataSet archiveDataset = new DataSet("Archive");
DataTable dsTable = archiveDataset.Tables.Add("Data");
dsTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
dsTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dsTable.Columns.Add("LastOperationBy", typeof(int));
dsTable.Columns.Add("Time", typeof(DateTime))
```

Once the Dataset is create, we are filling values as follows

```
 DataRow dataRow = dsTable.NewRow();
 dataRow["Id"] = source.Id;
 dataRow["Name"] = source.Name;
 dataRow["LastOperationBy"] = source.LastOperationBy;
 dataRow["Time"] = source.LaunchTime;
```

Is there any better and managed way of doing this. can I make the code more easy to write using enum or anything else to reduce the efforts?

Comment: what are you using the dataset for?

Comment: @Simon - I am using Dataset to export data to a XML file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using a [Typed Dataset](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320714).

This should get rid of the `["<column_name>"]` ugliness.

If the dataset has a structure similar to tables in a database, then Visual Studio makes it really easy to create one: just click *Add* -> *New Item* somewhere in the solution and choose *DataSet*. VS will show a designer where you can drag tables from your server explorer.

**Update (after response to Simon's comment):**
A typed dataset is in fact an XSD (XML Schema Definition).
What I did in a similar case was:

- created an empty DataSet (using *Add* -> *New Item* -> *DataSet*)
- opened the newly created file with a text editor (by dafault, in VS it shows the XSD designer)
- paste the XSD that I had created manually

You could also choose to use the designer to create the schema.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your comment "I am using Dataset to export data to a XML file" I recommend using a different technology such as

- Linq to XML http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx or
- Xml Serialzation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

Or better yet of is doesnt **have** to be XML (and you only want hierarchical readable text consider JSON instead http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can bind dataset in two way first one is using database second one is add manually. 
After create column for dataset you can add using `Loops` you can add it if you have 10000 of entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Reflection`. Another option is to use `EntityFramework` or `NHibernate` to map the columnnames and datastructure columns and then avoid these code to fill each field manually. But they will add more complexity. Also Performance wise the your code is better.